# ggMarginal: how to customize boxplot size and order?

Tags: r, ggplot2, width, customization, boxplot

I am using ggMarginal to add boxplots on the side of x and y axes of a scatterplot. I am facing some difficulties to customize it.

I would like to :

- have all boxplots with the same width
- customize boxplot order to have the same order for x and y axes (i.e. boxplot green, yellow, blue, red, brown and purple for both axes)

[image]

Here the code I am using:

```
ggplot(my_data)+
geom_point(aes(O,H, color= ID,group=ID),size=5)+
scale_color_manual(name="",
                 labels=c("b","d","g","o","s","s"))

ggMarginal(my_data, groupColour = TRUE, groupFill = TRUE, type="boxplot")
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I assume it's asking to reorder the marginal boxplot. On the right-hand side, the boxplot is in a consistent order with the legend (start with green than yellow). However, on the top panel, the order of boxplot is random.